# Magento - process wysiwyg filed in custom Module

Tags: php, magento

I've created a Magento Module that contains a wysiwyg filed.
When I use the "Insert image" button of the wysiwyg I get this code:

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/slide.jpg"}}" alt=""/>
```

with whitespace before the image path (this is how it works in the CMS as well).
I'm trying to process this filed using this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('slideshow/slide')->getCollection()->addPositonSort()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())->getItems();     
foreach ($collection as $slide) {    
    $contentToParse = $slide->getImage(); 
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
    $html = $processor->filter($contentToParse);
    echo $html;
}
```

But it keeps the whitespace in the image path:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/media/ wysiwyg/slide1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

and the image is not showing.

How should I process this filed?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
`<img src="{{skin url="wysiwyg/slide.jpg"}}" alt="" />`
```

Instead of

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/slide.jpg"}}" alt=""/>
```

It works

Comment: It will work if I'll edit the code the wysiwyg creates. But I want to be able to use the insert image functionality as is without editing the code it inserts

Comment: check the variable that used to insert image
may be any blank spaces present in that variable

Comment: Which variable you refer to? The "insert image" functionality adds the whitespace before the image path in all of Magento. it's not just in my Module. If I insert an image to a static block it works the same, but on the fronend the image path is displayed without the whitespace

Comment: what is in $slide
i think $contentToParse not get the image 
please check it

Comment: I've updated the code in my question. Image is the name of the filed that contains the content from the wysiwyg, So I get the content from the wysiwyg and try to process it with the CMS helper

Comment: try skin url instead of meadia url

Comment: This is the code the "insert image" button inserts. I don't want to change it, I just want to process it correctly